# Getting the object that is created before this object

Tags: django, django-models

I want a delta between two objects:

```
class Point(models.Model):

    measurement = models.ForeignKey(Measurement)
    time = models.DateTimeField()
    value = models.FloatField()

    def delta(self):
        measurement = self.measurement.point_set.order_by('time')
        measurement = measurement[-2]
        return self.value - measurement.value
```

But this obviously just works for the latest object. Is there a way to get the predecessors of the self.object in a time-wise sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def delta(self):
    try:
        my_predecessor = self.objects\
            .filter(measurement_id=self.measurement_id, pk__lt=self.pk)\
            .order_by('pk')[-1]
    except IndexError:
        # there is no previous object
        return None
    else:
        return self.time - my_predecessor.time
```

`self.measurement_id` should be synonymous to `self.measurement.pk`

`pk` means primary key. The values are normally automatically assigned from a sequence.

`pk__lt=self.pk` means "objects whose pk is **L**ess **T**han mine", or "created earlier than me". More [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-lookups/).

I `order_by('pk')`, so I ensure selecting `Point` objects in the order they were created (comparing integer fields is always faster than comparing `DateTimeField` objects. You can always replace it with `order_by('time')` if you will have some doubts :)

`_id` is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/#field-lookups). I used it to build a more optimal SQL query that only selects from one table (doesn't join the table of the `Measurement` model). The [difference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#order-by) between `_id` and `__id`.

Finally, `[-1]` takes the last object. Django [queryset slicing](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) works very similar to [python slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation).